# Bash - array as argument

Tags: bash

I have a problem with using array as parameter in function.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function array_param
{
  local ARRAY_s; local ARRAY_t; local OPTIND

  while getopts 's:t:' opt ; do
    case "$opt" in
      s) ARRAY_s=$OPTARG;;
      t) ARRAY_t=$OPTARG;;      
    esac
  done
  shift $((OPTIND-1))
  echo "ARRAY_s=${ARRAY_s[@]}; ARRAY_t=${ARRAY_t[@]}"
}

array_s=(100 200 300)
array_t=(0 10 3585)

array_param -s ${array_s} -t ${array_t}
```

Why is only the first element assigned to variables ARRAY_s and ARRAY_t?

> Result: 
>   ARRAY_s=100; ARRAY_t=0

Comment: `${array_s}` is the first element of the array. Try `"${array_s[@]}"`

Comment: `ARRAY_s=$OPTARG` is also only a string assignment, not an array assignment. What are you trying to do exactly? Copy arrays following the parameters to `ARRAY_s` and `ARRAY_t`?

Comment: Yes, I try to assign the -s and -t parameters to a variable and use it in a function (I only inserted a fragment that I can't solve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`${array_s}` is equivalent to `${array_s[0]}`, that's why only the first element is assigned:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

array_param() {   
    local opt OPTIND tmp
    local -a arr_s arr_t

    while getopts 's:t:' opt; do
        case $opt in
            s) tmp=$OPTARG[@]; arr_s=("${!tmp}") ;;
            t) tmp=$OPTARG[@]; arr_t=("${!tmp}") ;;
        esac
    done
    echo "arr_s = ${arr_s[*]}"
    echo "arr_t = ${arr_t[*]}"
}

arr1=(100 200 300)
arr2=(0 10 3585)

array_param -s arr1 -t arr2
```

- `local opt`: you should localize all variables, even `opt`
- `tmp=$OPTARG[@]`: creates a tepmporary variable of this format: `array_name[@]`
- `arr=(values)`: array assignment
- `${!tmp}`: [variable indirection](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html). It first expands to the value of `$tmp`, and then expands once more to the final result: `${!tmp} -> ${array_name[@]} -> all values`

---

You can also use [nameref](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameters.html) (makes the code more readable but requires `bash` 4.3 or later):

```
s) local -n tmp=$OPTARG; arr_s=("${tmp[@]}") ;;
t) local -n tmp=$OPTARG; arr_t=("${tmp[@]}") ;;
```

Answer (score 1):

modifying slightly function (using lowercase for variable, and using array semantics)

```
array_param() {
    local l_array_s l_array_t OPTIND

    while getopts 's:t:' opt ; do
        case "$opt" in
        s) l_array_s+=( "$OPTARG" ) ;;
        t) l_array_t+=( "$OPTARG" ) ;;
        esac
    done
    shift $((OPTIND-1))
    echo "l_array_s=${l_array_s[*]}; l_array_t=${l_array_t[*]}"
}
```

can be called

```
array_param "${array_s[@]/#/-s}" "${array_t[@]/#/-t}"
```

- `${array_s[@]/#/-s}`  notation is specificc to bash, `#` matches start of string and is replaced  by `-s` for each element in array.

following printf to understand how arguments are passed

```
printf "<%s> " "${array_s[@]/#/-s}" "${array_t[@]/#/-t}"
```

also compare

```
printf "<%s> " "${array_s}"
printf "<%s> " "${array_s[@]}"
printf "<%s> " "${array_s[*]}"
```

Comment: You are missing quotes `"$OPTARG"`. Otherwise, interesting use of `/#/-s`...+1.

Comment: @PesaThe, true, fixed

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass `array_s` and `array_t` as array, `getopts` will get only first element of each array.

But, you can try to use C-style `for` loop like that to increment local `ARRAY_s` and `ARRAY_t` variable, print them in the end:

```
    $ cat optarg.sh 
    #!/usr/bin/env bash

    function array_param
    {
      local OPTIND

      while getopts 's:t:' opt ; do
        case "$opt" in
            s) ARRAY_s+=("${OPTARG}");;
            t) ARRAY_t+=("${OPTARG}");;      
        esac
      done
      shift $((OPTIND-1))
    }

    array_s=(100 200 300)
    array_t=(0 10 3585)

    #Works if only array_s length equal array_t length.
    for ((args=0; args<${#array_s[@]}; args++))
    do
        array_param -s ${array_s[args]} -t ${array_t[args]}
    done

    echo "ARRAY_s=${ARRAY_s[@]}; ARRAY_t=${ARRAY_t[@]}"
```

Output:

```
ARRAY_s=100 200 300; ARRAY_t=0 10 3585
```